# PHP MySQL fetching columns as different arrays from the same results row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

Suppose, I have a table of events and I want to get all the events of some day (e.g. 2018-01-02)

```
|   e1    |     d1     |   e2    |     d2     |   e3    |     d3     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| event A | 2018-01-01 | event B | 2018-01-02 | event C | 2018-01-02 |
| event D | 2018-01-01 | NULL    | NULL       | NULL    | NULL       |
| NULL    | NULL       | event E | 2018-01-02 | event F | 2018-01-03 |
```

The problem is when I try to fetch results like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE d1='2018-01-02' OR d2='2018-01-02' OR d3='2018-01-02' "
```

I'm given the whole row of results (in this case - all three rows).
But I would like to get the separate results array with event and date. Like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            event => event B
            date => 2018-01-02
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            event => event C
            date => 2018-01-02
        )
)
```

As for now, I did it this ugly way, executing 3 queries and joining their results:

```
$Sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT e1 AS event, d1 AS date FROM table WHERE d1='2018-01-02'");
$Sql->execute();
$Arr1 = $Sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$Sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT e2 AS event, d2 AS date FROM table WHERE d2='2018-01-02'");
$Sql->execute();
$Arr2 = $Sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$Sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT e3 AS event, d3 AS date FROM table WHERE d3='2018-01-02'");
$Sql->execute();
$Arr3 = $Sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$Arr=array();
foreach($Arr1 AS $a){
 $Arr[]=array($a['event'],$a['date']);
}
foreach($Arr2 AS $a){
 $Arr[]=array($a['event'],$a['date']);
}
foreach($Arr3 AS $a){
 $Arr[]=array($a['event'],$a['date']);
}

print_r($Arr);
```

But I'm sure there should be some more adequate way to do this. Either by modifying SQL or PHP.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do the three query with a Union statement maybe ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html
try something like this

```
$Sql=$conn->prepare("(SELECT e1 AS event, d1 AS date FROM table WHERE d1='2018-01-02') UNION (SELECT e2 AS event, d2 AS date FROM table WHERE d2='2018-01-02') UNION (SELECT e3 AS event, d3 AS date FROM table WHERE d3='2018-01-02') ");
$Sql->execute();
$Arr = $Sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

alse note that date is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) so you might have to write it with back ticks... not sure though because I simply don't use them ;)

Comment: `date` is a keyword; not a Reserved Keyword though. So no need of using backticks around it.

Comment: Thank you! 
I was playing quite a bit with join statements, but didn't came up with this simple and elegant solution!